# 'TextStyle?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextStyle'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Getting this null safety error while working on my flutter app.

```
The argument type 'TextStyle?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextStyle'.
```

Here is the code snippet that is throwing this error:

```dart
ButtonStyle(textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(Theme.of(context).textTheme.button))
```

VS Code suggest this solution to put not operator at the end of the argument.

```
ButtonStyle(textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(Theme.of(context).textTheme.button!))
```

**Question:** Is this a good practice to use **!** in my code and what other solutions are possible in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material state properties represent values that depend on a widget's material "state". The state is encoded as a set of MaterialState values, like MaterialState.focused, MaterialState.hovered, MaterialState.pressed. For example the InkWell.overlayColor defines the color that fills the ink well when it's pressed (the "splash color"), focused, or hovered. The InkWell uses the overlay color's resolve method to compute the color for the ink well's current state.

You could use only Theme of context to use theme textStyle like this:

```
Text("copied text theme",
 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
 style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button)
```

Comment: So I should instead out the styles in the Text Widget instead of the Button Widget?

Comment: You can define your styles in the MaterialTheme, any how I followed your snippet to use button text style for the styling the text widget under discussion. :)

Comment: I actually wanted to style the text inside the button. So using materialstateproperty would be a wrong choice?

Comment: Yeah, you could simply use TextStyle() or Theme.of(context) textTheme.

Answer (score 19):

You can also get this error if you imported wrong library for the material TextStyle.

This may happen when you used:

```
import 'dart:ui';
```

Instead of:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Answer (score 2):

MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith((states) => TextStyle(fontSize: 12),

You can use .***resolveWith*** Method to create a MaterialStateTextStyle from a MaterialPropertyResolver callback function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Initialize Your Style in the Buildcontext, Example :

```
 var _styleType = Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .body1
                                .copyWith(color: Colors.white);
```

Then Apply It to the Widget :

```
Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: new Text("\u00a9 TasnuvaOshin",
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: _styleType),
                      ),
```

Comment: So instead of putting the style to the button I should add it to the text?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 2+ years old but I think the real (EDIT: Simpler, because previous answer works) answer is still missing. The issue is that it's looking for a non-null TextTheme and you're providing a nullable TextTheme. BUT the property itself is looking for nullable TextTheme. It's your line that is making it look for a non-null TextTheme

So in this line:

```
ButtonStyle(textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(Theme.of(context).textTheme.button))
```

This property can accept a nullable TextStyle:

> ButtonStyle( textStyle:

This expression returns a nullable TextStyle

> Theme.of(context).textTheme.button)

It's your type declaration that is saying it can't be nullable:

> MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>

You just need to add a ? to your type:

```
MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle?>
```

Comment: That’s the correct way, you handle a nullable property correctly even if it is nil (duh). The ! tells the compiler to_crash_ if it is nil. It means “I know it could be nil, but I promise it isn’t, please crash if I’m wrong”. The compiler accepts it but may crash at runtime. Your solution will work just fine with nil.

Comment: @gnasher729 Sorry, you're right, it does work, but it's a strange choice to change the type to non nullable, then add the exclamation mark, for no reason. My choice of language is a  little off but just reflects that the real mistake originally was changing the type without any reason to.